# UI Useability - Reordering and merging columns

Tags: jquery, user-interface, usability

I'm writing a little web-based utility for my brother who needs to merge columns in a CSV file. I know things like this surely exist somewhere, but a large part of this is that is a fun little exercise.

Anyways, I'm trying to figure out the best/neatest way to present the part of the UI where he reorders the columns and chooses which columns get merged.

The jQuery UI "selectable" interaction provides about 85% of what I need - the simple reordering of the columns - but I'm having a bit of a rough time with the merging. What I'm trying to do is make it so that "merged" columns become a nested list under a single item.

For example:

```
<ul id="columns">
<li>Column 1</li>
<li>Column 2</li>
</ul>
```

would become:

```
<ul id="columns">
<li>Column 1<ul class="merge"><li>Column 2</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

This is proving to be a bit more of a pain than I anticipated, so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for a better way to present the overall UI. I'm fairly comfortable in jQuery, so bonus points if it can be done in jQuery :D

@dylanfm: This *isn't* tabular data - it's just a list of column *names*, but no actual data. Besides, the specific HTML element I use is hardly at the heart of what I'm asking.

@smo: I like the simplicity of your idea, but the problem is that there are several *dozen* different columns, so listing every column once per column would unfortunately be out of the question.

@strager: That's pretty much exactly what I've been trying to do, it's just that particulars of making UI respond the way I want have been giving me problems. I'll give you the answer for now, and I guess it's back to the salt mines for me.

Comment: What are the exact points you are having trouble with?

Comment: @Javache -- Sorry, I just saw the comment.

I've uploaded what I've done so far here:

http://new.dandoes.net/Tools/Csv

The area in question is under "2. Column Mappings". Most of it works, except when dragging "Test Column 01" around - it tends to get stuck wherever its drop instead of reverting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic steps:

1. Grab the list of columns to be merged as an array of <li>'s.

   - If you're merging two already-merged columns (or one of the colums is already merged), extract each column in the group.  In your structure, you'd want to make "Column 1" have its own <li> without the child <ul>.
   - You'd probably want to clone these, as you'll be deleting the original nodes in (6).
2. Create a new <ul> node, adding the proper "merged" className.
3. Add all the <li>'s you gathered in (1), except the first one, and insert them as children to the <ul>.
4. Insert the <ul> as the last child of the first <li> you gathered in (1).
5. Insert the <li> (parent in (4)) as a child of the column list ($('#columns')).
6. Delete the original columns which you were going to merge.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to stick with using tables for tabular data, unordered lists don't seem to suit the content as much.